# PHP stdClass Object, how to get element with the 0 index

Tags: php, stdclass

I have a stdClass Object like this:

```
print_r($myobj);

stdClass Object(
[0] => testData
);
```

So it is clear that I cannot get the value by `$myobj->0`.

For getting this value I convert the object to an array, but are there any ways to get without converting?

Comment: you can do it using `echo $myobj->{0};`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
$obj = new stdClass();

$obj->{0} = 1;

echo $obj->{0};
```

source: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php

Answer (score 0):

So firstly, even though it appears from `print_r()`'s output that the property is literally integer `0`, it is not. If you call `var_dump()` on the object instead, you'll see that, in fact, it looks like this:

```
php > var_dump($myobject);
object(stdClass)#2 (1) {
  ["0"]=>
  string(4) "testData"
}
```

So how do you access a property named `0` when PHP won't let you access `$myobject->0`? Use the special [Complex (curly) syntax](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex):

```
php > echo $myobject->{0};
test
php > echo $myobject->{'0'};
test
php >
```

You can use this method to access property names that are not considered valid syntax.